# google.visualisation.DataTable() positioning pagination div

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-visualization, visualization

I have this data in a Google DataTable:

[image]

And I want to position the page buttons on top of the table. But it seems to me Google doesn't support to do this. Is there any best approach do you guys know?

[image]

HERE IS jsfiddle link what I am trying now.

```
jsfiddle.net/Kwangsub_Ahn/ohh8397h/7/

HTML
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>

JAVASCRIPT
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
    packages: ["table"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Project');
    data.addColumn('string', 'System');
    data.addColumn('number', 'No');
    data.addRows([
        ['7/31/2014', 'project1', 'system1', 5],
        ['5/2/2014', 'project2', 'system2', 2],
        ['5/2/2014', 'project1', 'system1', 5],
        ['1/31/2014', 'project3', 'system4', 1]
   ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    var id = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(id);

    table.draw(view, {
        allowHtml: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 10
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  there aren't any standard options you can set,

but you can move the button row manually,

when the chart's `'ready'` and `'page'` events fire

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', moveButtons);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'page', moveButtons);

    function moveButtons() {
      var content = id.children[0].children[1];
      var parent = content.parentNode;
      parent.insertBefore(content, parent.children[0]);
    }
```

---

**2)** the chart will move the buttons back to the bottom after the `'sort'` and `'page'` events...

using `moveButtons` for the `'page'` event works fine,

but need to handle `'sort'` differently

- if you **don't want to allow sorting**, simply set the following option, and don't attach an event...

`sort: 'event'`

- if you **want to allow sorting**, you'll still need to set the above option,
  but you'll also have to handle manually sorting the table

`sort: 'event'`

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', sortTable);

function sortTable(sortOptions) {
  data.sort([{
    column: sortOptions.column,
    desc: !sortOptions.ascending
  }]);

  options.sortColumn = sortOptions.column;
  options.sortAscending = sortOptions.ascending;

  table.draw(data, options);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawTable,
  packages: ['table']
});

function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Project');
    data.addColumn('string', 'System');
    data.addColumn('number', 'No');
    data.addRows([
        ['7/31/2014', 'project1', 'system1', 5],
        ['5/2/2014', 'project2', 'system2', 2],
        ['5/2/2014', 'project1', 'system1', 5],
        ['1/31/2014', 'project3', 'system4', 1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        allowHtml: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        page: 'enable',
        pageSize: 2,
        sort: 'event'
    };


    var id = document.getElementById('table_div');
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(id);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', moveButtons);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'page', moveButtons);

    function moveButtons() {
      var content = id.children[0].children[1];
      var parent = content.parentNode;
      parent.insertBefore(content, parent.children[0]);
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', sortTable);

    function sortTable(sortOptions) {
      data.sort([{
        column: sortOptions.column,
        desc: !sortOptions.ascending
      }]);

      options.sortColumn = sortOptions.column;
      options.sortAscending = sortOptions.ascending;

      table.draw(data, options);
    }

    table.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: recommend using the newer library `loader.js` (vs. `jsapi`), according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...